# CSS Grid - continues after end?

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS grid that works great except for one problem.

At the end of the section with the grid, I have some links. I can't click on the links, though. When I try, a section the size of the grid highlights. Basically, there is an invisible section under the grid that blocks the elements below the grid. Any advice?

Here is the CSS

```
.course-grid2 { position: relative;  float: left; width: 192px; height: 495px; margin: 0 10px 10px 10px; }
.course-grid2.row { width:100%; height: 150px; margin: 0 0 10px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; }
.course-grid2.row:last-child { border-bottom:hidden; }
.course-grid2.row img { float: left; margin: 0 10px 10px 0; }
#main .course-grid2 p { font-size: 12px; line-height: 18px; margin: 0 0 5px 0 !important; }
#main .course-grid2 p.short-description { font-size: 12px; height: 80px; }
#main .course-grid2 h3 { margin: 0 0 10px 0; font-size: 17px; font-weight: normal; }
#main .course-grid2.grid h3 { height: 40px; }
#main .course-grid2.row h3 { font-size:18px; }
#main .course-grid2.row .c-info { margin-left:140px; }
#main .course-grid2.row .links { height:28px; margin-top:10px; }
#main .course-grid2 .small { font-size: 11px; }
#main .course-grid2 > .links { margin: 10px 0; }
#main .links form { display: inline; }
#main .links a, #main .links input[type=submit] {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #f0f0f0 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f0f0f0), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #f0f0f0 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #f0f0f0 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #f0f0f0 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,  #f0f0f0 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f0f0f0', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 );
    border: 1px solid #ccc; }
#main .links a:hover, #main .links input[type=submit]:hover { background: #f8f8f8; color: #111; border: 1px solid #aaa; box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #ddd; }
span.price { color: red; font-weight: 700; font-size: 14px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use the overflow property with the value of hidden inside your #main, I'm not really sure but if you can provide a screenshot I might be of some help. :)

Comment: That would be great. Here is the problem...the links at the bottom can't be clicked because of this invisible property that is highlighted (there are two others, one on each side)  [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/bK2dL7Z.png)

Comment: I apologize for wasting your time, unfortunately I cannot locate the error by just looking from your css above. I was wondering why that blue box.. appeared there, maybe you have to look somewhere in your css with the background-color property with the value of #b0d6ff, and you can start from there. :(